# How to make a simple decision tree

Tags: graph-theory, decision-tree

I have tree that is saved in adjacent matrix. I have the following structure 
[image: Structure]

I want it to work the following way. I get integers (A,B,C etc.) parameters and want to get a final decision depending on some logic. For example, if A parameter is less than 5, I want the decision flow go to the node 2, where B parameter is checked. Then if B parameter is more than 10, I want it to go to the node 5 where C parameter is checked and so on.

My question is about how can this decision be done in an elegant way? How can I save this info (which node should be next depending on the parameter value) in a database?
I don't want to use just if statements cause these trees will be automatically generated

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and the problem you are encountering. Also please review [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are asking an open ended question without any code you have tried.

Comment: Hello. The point is I don't have any code yet cause I don't know how to do it :)